# How to make google sheets index from values in column and hyperlink those to sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bunch of data I want to put in to multiple sheets, and to do it manually would take time and I would like to learn scripting too.

So say I have a sheet with the states in one column.
I would like to have a script make new sheets based off the values of that column, and make a hyperlink to those sheets, and sort the sheets alphabetically.
In each sheet, I need to have the A1 cell the same name as the sheet.

[Here is an example of states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LjDx.png)

Any suggestions would be helpful

Edit:
This is code that can make sheets based on the values of the columns.

```
  function makeTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var last = sheet.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet

  //loop through the code until each row creates a tab.
  for(var i=0; i<last; i++){

    var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).getValue();//get the range in column A and get the value.

    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//create a new sheet with the value
  }
}
```

(note the "sheet.getRange(i+2,1" assumes a header, so pulls from the first column, starting on the second row)

I still need to:

- Add a hyper link in the index sheet to the State's sheet: example: A2 on the Index sheet
  would be `=HYPERLINK("#gid=738389498","Alabama")`
- Also I need the A1 cell of the State's page to have the same info as
  the index. example: Alabama's A1 cell would be `=Index!A2`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this script:

```
 function createSheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var indexSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Index');
  var indexSheetRange = indexSheet.getDataRange();
  var values = indexSheetRange.getValues();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE_the_state');
  templateSheet.activate();
  var sheetIds = [],
      state,
      sheetId,
      links = [];

  for (var i = 1 ; i < values.length ; i++){
    state = values[i][0];
    sheetId = undefined;
      try{
        var sheet =  ss.insertSheet(state,  {template: templateSheet});
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        sheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([['=hyperlink("#gid=0&range=A' +(i+1)+'","go back to index")',state]]);
        sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
      }
      catch (e) { Logger.log('Sheet %s already exists ' , sheet)}
    sheetIds.push([sheetId,state]);
    } 
    sheetIds.forEach(function(x){
      links.push(['=HYPERLINK("#gid='+x[0]+'&range=A1","'+x[1]+'")']);
    });
    indexSheet.getRange(2,1,links.length,links[0].length).setValues(links) // in this case it is clear to us from the outset that links[0].length is 1, so we could have written 1
}
```

Note that in my version, I created a template sheet from which to base all the state sheets from.  This wasn't what you asked for, but I wanted to see what it would do.
The resulting sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rk00eXPzkfov5e3D3AKOVQA2UdvE5b8roG3-WeI4znE/edit?usp=sharing

Indeed, I was surprised at how long it took to create the full sheet with all the states - more than 250 secs.  I looked at the execution log, which I have added to the sheet in its own tab.  There it is plain to see that the code is quick, but sometimes (why only sometimes, I don't know) adding a new tab to the spreadsheet and/or flushing the formulas on the spreadsheet is very slow.   I don't know how to speed it up. Any suggestions welcome. (I could try the Google Sheets API v4, probably would be much faster ... but that is much more work and tougher to do.)

Comment: rather than a forEach, you could use `const links = sheetIds.map(function (x) { return ....; });` It's often useful to link to the API documentation for "advanced" `Array` methods that accept callbacks (i.e. filter, map, reduce, forEach, sort)

Comment: map sounds tight - but sometimes I think I might need eg column headings already in the array.

WRT docs, I've provided a complete, non-trivial spreadsheet+G A Script model for the OP/future learners. When I started out, this  was exactly the kind of 'complete' implementation that I would have wanted. Fundamental js is well documented everywhere - it's easy to google. But not spreadsheets + script.  These can be so frustrating at many turns. Models motivate me to get to the bigger picture. With it's grounding I would then google its parts (e.g. forEach) with peace, confidence and glee. IMHO

Comment: `Array#unshift`. Providing links to content that *you know is not intuitive/easy* is a good indicator to learners of where they can find information, and also encouragement because you explicitly indicate that there is help for how this thing works and what it does - they don't have to **also** figure out how to google that concept.

Comment: Is it your opinion that the value of a spreadsheet model is degraded below a threshold of relevant value to the OP/ future learners when  presented in a manner as I have here (without a good sowing of content links to JS info; with shaky programming (no unshift, map)?